# Get final result Multijob from several hosts (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a MultiJob Project with structure:

```
Master MultiJob Project (Job)
 |----- Phase 1
            |------> JOB A 
            |------> JOB D
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB B
            |------> JOB D
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB C
```

Main Job (Master MultiJob Project) run on the Master, but other jobs can run on another free worker, but result of each Job(A/B/C/D) must send to Master MultiJob to collect result and get summury result of all jobs.
When all Jobs was on one host I use:

```
 ln -s $WORKSPACE/$REPORTSDIR
```

where $WORKSPACE I send from Master MultiJob like a parameter, but if they on differents hosts I cann't use this solution. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wait for sub-jobs to complete. They must keep the reports as artifacts.
2. From master job get sub-jobs build numbers and copy artifacts from finished sub-jobs.

This is in general what you have to do. But you must be more clear what type of build are you using - pipeline or simple freestyle project? You might need to install Copy Artifact Plugin.

Comment: Just simple freestyle project

Comment: How do you trigger sub-jobs?

Comment: We use MultiJob plugin